# Directly prove using the definition of convergence $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2 +1 }{4n -1} = \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

The definition of convergence is :
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n =l \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n -l=0 $

So $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2 +1 }{4n -1} =\infty \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2 +1 }{4n -1} -\infty =0$

and we have to show that $ \forall n > X,|\frac{n^2 +1 }{4n -1} -\infty| < \epsilon $.

Comment: You can't subtract infinity from both sizes. That is not how limits to $\infty$ work. The definition you are using at the start is for finite limits, but there is a different definition for $\lim a_n=+\infty$.

Comment: We say $\lim a_n = \infty$ if, for every real $C$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n> N$ $a_n>C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$4n-1\leq 4n\quad\text{and}\quad n^2+1\geq n^2.$$ Therefore $$\frac{n^2+1}{4n-1}\geq \frac{n^2}{4n}=\frac{n}{4}.$$
Then, if $M>0$, if you take $N=\lfloor 4M\rfloor+1$, you have that $$\frac{n^2+1}{4n-1}>M$$ when $n\geq N$ what prove the claim.

Comment: Can also proceed with $\quad \frac{n^2 + 1}{4 n - 1} - \frac{n}{4} = \frac{n + 4}{4 (4 n - 1)}$

Answer (score 2):

To show that a function f(n) goes to $\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$, we need to show that for any $\alpha$ > 0, there will be a $\delta$ > 0 such that for all n > $\delta$, f(n) > $\alpha$.

You function is f(n) = $\frac{n^2 +1 }{4n -1}$ >$\frac{n^2  }{4n}$ > $\frac{n}{4}$

and we need the f(n) > $\alpha$, which can be satisfied if we have $\frac{n}{4}$ > $\alpha$ i.e. n > 4$\alpha$. So our required $\delta$ = 4$\alpha$ and you have shown the required thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but as I get pretty the same one I choosed to answer it fully so maybe it will help other futur student and mostly it helps me to improve myself on rigourous mathematical writting.

First let's recall that the true definition of $\lim_n  a_n = \infty $ is: $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}^+ \; \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \; \forall n > N \Rightarrow a_n>M $

First let pay attention to the following inequalities:

- $n^2+1>n^2$ as $1>0$
- $4n-1<4n$ as $-1<0$
- So by the two inequalities above: $\frac{n^2+1}{4n-1}>\frac{n^2}{4n}=\frac{n}{4}$
- So now for all $M>0$ if $N=4M \Rightarrow \forall n>N=4M$ we get the following inequality $\frac{n}{4}>\frac{N}{4}=\frac{4M}{4}=M$

We can conclude by writting the above definition with the help of all the inequalities we ve written above.
$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}^+ \; \exists N=4M \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \; \forall n > N=4M \Rightarrow a_n=\frac{n^2+1}{4n-1}>\frac{n^2}{4n}=\frac{n}{4}>\frac{N}{4}=\frac{4M}{4}=M$
Which is your proof by definition.